# Minimal document size in IBM Cloudant Bluemix

Tags: json, ibm-cloud, cloudant

What is the minimal document size in Cloudant?

If I insert the following JSON:

```
 {"_id",1234}
```

or

```
{"_id":NumberLong(1),"g":"1383,5,2000,1"}
```

Is there a difference in document size of these two?

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet is not valid JSON, and therefore not a valid document in Cloudant. I believe that `NumberLong` in your second code snippet is a type that is specific to MongoDB.

Cloudant (and CouchDB) store documents as JSON, not BSON like MongoDB. As for size of a document, pretty much what you see is what you'll get. If it's a larger JSON object, then it will be a larger document.